# In order to achieve differentially private machine learning can one simply apply the Laplace mechanism after an SGD scheme? If so does it work well?

Tags: differential-privacy, machine-learning

Consider a standard supervised machine learning problem on private data. Instead of using DPSGD, suppose that one uses a non-private SGD scheme to produce optimal model parameters $\theta$ (done in the private data enclave, as with DPSGD), and releases publicly $\theta + \eta$, with $\eta \sim$ Laplace$(0, \varepsilon)$ (meaning choose variance so we get $\varepsilon-$DP).

Is this a valid method of differentially private machine learning? (I think it is).

If so, how does it compare in terms of accuracy and privacy to DPSGD? I don't recall seeing it in any papers, in particular not in the original paper of [Abadi et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.00133)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this (can be) valid.
In particular, if one views the function

$$
D\mapsto F(D) := \theta
$$
that maps a dataset to model parameters as a mechanism, you can apply standard techniques to post-process this mechanism with Laplace noise and achieve differential privacy.
To do this though, one needs a bound on what is known as the ($\ell_1$) sensitivity of the function.
See [section 3.2](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Eaaroth/chatgpt_lecture_notes.pdf) for context, but this is defined as

$$
\Delta F = \sup_{D\sim D'}\lVert F(D) - F(D')\rVert_1
$$
Here, $D\sim D'$ means the set of all pairs of databases $(D, D')$ that differ in a single entry.
If you can compute/bound $\Delta F$, then releasing $F(D)+e$ for $e\gets\mathsf{Lap}(\Delta F/\epsilon)$ will be $\epsilon$-DP.

As for whether this works well, I do not personally know the practical numbers.
I imagine it is worse though.
This is for the simple reason that it *ignores* the impact of privacy amplification.
Privacy amplification (roughly) is the idea that for some mechanism of independent interest $F$, one can often factor it into $F = G\circ H$, where $H$ has some incidental differentially private properties.
For example, perhaps during training one [subsamples](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.01647) the data (for efficiency purposes).
This *also* has privacy benefits.
The naive analysis you suggest ignores these privacy benefits, and therefore achieves a *higher* amount of privacy than required, likely leading to worse performance.

Comment: thanks. I figured it out at the same time! Glad to see that you confirmed my thoughts. Thanks for the links to the subsampling to get amplification.

Answer (score 1):

The method of adding noise to $\theta$ produced from a (non-private) SGD scheme (or any optimization algorithm) will provide differential privacy if we can can compute the sensitivity of $\theta$.

Suppose our loss function is $L(\theta, X) = \sum_{X,Y} l(x,y)$ (so $l$ is a per-data-point loss).
Using regular gradient descent, we would initialize $\theta_0$, then  for $K$ steps perform $\theta_{k+1} \leftarrow \theta_k -\alpha \nabla L(\theta_k, X, y)$

We wish to release the final $\theta_K$ with the Laplace mechanism. We must compute its sensitivity to get the variance of the Laplace distribution.
Let $(X_1, Y_1)$, $(X_2, Y_2)$ be our neighboring datasets with lone different row denoted $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)$.
Then $L(X_1, Y_1, \theta) - L(X_2, Y_2, \theta) = l(x_1, y_1, \theta) - l(x_2, y_2, \theta)$, and we see the difference in gradients is  $\nabla L(X_1, Y_1, \theta) - \nabla L(X_2, Y_2, \theta) = \nabla l(x_1, y_1, \theta) - \nabla l(x_2, y_2, \theta)$ is the difference of the per-data-point loss across the lone row of differing values.

So estimating the sensitivity $\sup |\theta_K(X_1,Y_1) - \theta_K(X_2, Y_2)|$ is hard, even in this simplified case with identical fixed starting position, learning rate using basic gradient descent. It can be thought of as considering two ODEs with the same initial condition $\theta_0$ where the update is slightly different. Comparing the updat steps:

1. $\dot{\theta} = \theta_{k+1} - \theta_k = -\alpha \nabla L(\theta_k, X_1, Y_1) $
2. $\dot{\theta} = \theta_{k+1} - \theta_k = -\alpha \nabla L(\theta_k, X_2, y_2) =  -\alpha \nabla L(\theta_k, X_1, Y_1) +  \alpha \nabla l(x_1, y_1, \theta_k)  -\alpha \nabla l(x_2, y_2, \theta_k)$.

We know that in many quite simple ODE systems, minor differences in the first few steps can lead to large differences as time progresses.